# how to represent a seq in midje test

Tags: clojure

```
(fact "Checking :time has been removed"
      (remove-date [{:time 1 :a 2} {:c 3 :time 4}]) => (seq '({:a 2} {:c 4})))
```

In the above test the `remove-date` function returns a seq `({:a 2} {:c 4})` How do I represent the seq on the right hand side ? (The above doesnt work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above works for me, you just got the {:c 4} in your assertion wrong. It should be {:c 3}.

```
(fact "Checking :time has been removed"
      (remove-date [{:time 1 :a 2} {:c 3 :time 4}]) => (seq '({:a 2} {:c 3})))
```

In fact you don't need the `seq` call:

```
(fact "Checking :time has been removed"
      (remove-date [{:time 1 :a 2} {:c 3 :time 4}]) => '({:a 2} {:c 3}))
```

I tested it with midje 1.5.0 and clojure 1.4.0

Comment: Thanks @dAni , that was really a silly mistake ): Also is there a better idiom to the above test, instead of giving fixed values in the fact itself ?

Comment: You can always test if :time is in the result, but to be honest, your test just looks fine.